# How to write Subquery along with EXIST in Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to get a result as boolean using EXISTS keyword along with Subqueries. How to use subqueries in Spring boot JPA. Below is my query which works fine with sql, But not sure why not working with JPA Spring Boot.

**EXAMPLE :JPA QRY: SELECT EXISTS(SELECT t.test from Test t where t.id = ?1)**

Here I am getting true/false as expected with SQL, but getting below error with Spring boot JPA ?

**org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree**

Could you please let me know how to write the query using JPA without native using Native Query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The JpaRepository exposes existsById method which does what you want

```
boolean exists = repository.existsById(searchId)
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#existsById(ID)

Comment: Be carful with existsById because it used count(): https://blog.jooq.org/avoid-using-count-in-sql-when-you-could-use-exists/